# How is the best way to save MSSQL docker container data?

Tags: sql-server, docker, mssql-jdbc

I am going to use MSSQL server for a testing project and as I am on Mac I am going to use [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) to use it. As a shell, I will use DataGrip from jetbrains.
So, how is the best way if I want to save the data each time on my running container so that each time I started it, I can have my databases with their records?

Comment: you need to expose the volumes (which is what I do with postgres), [this blog](https://dbafromthecold.com/2020/07/17/sql-server-and-docker-compose/) had some good insight but personally I couldn't get it to work with my docker compose.

Comment: Can I use commit to save the container state? but I think the volume is better way... Thanks